# With the Silver Key artifact, what effects can I spend 1 less clue?

Tags: eldritch-horror

The description for the Silver Key artifact is

> Once per round, you may spend 1 less clue to pay for an effect

This boardgamegeek thread discusses it, but I am still not clear what effects this covers or doesn't cover.

https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1080669/silver-key-what-effect

My general thinking is most anything is valid as long as it isn't a specific clue that is needed to pay for an effect, i.e. a mystery that requires you to finish a research encounter and pay THAT clue toward solving it.

Comment: This thread seems to claim that anything is an effect if you spend clues: https://community.fantasyflightgames.com/index.php?/topic/110153-silver-key-artifact/

Comment: I'm leaning toward your thinking but still on the fence about cases, usually mystery solving, where they say to obtain a clue and then spend *that* clue to move forward, i.e. get an eldritch token to place on a mystery card. Given it's an artifact, I'm tempted to say yes to those cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After considering the links in this thread, I've concluded that the Silver Key artifact can be used anywhere you might spend a clue including re-rolls. The single situation I would say it cannot be used is where the wording says after resolving a research encounter, the investigator can spend a clue gained from that encounter to etc such as in the [Azathoth Occult Research mystery card](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/eldritch-horror/p3/Marketing%20Images/Mystery%20Card/01_OccultResearch.jpg).

The whole purpose of this wording seems to be to imply that the investigator should have succeeded in gaining *that* specific clue in order to spend a clue, and not allow one to circumvent it (i.e. via the Astronomer ability) to supply a clue.

Apart from that case, it's an artifact, so should be viewed as all manner of awesome. A 1 clue per round boon in every non-specific clue interpretation sounds fair game to me.